# Search for a value in dictionary to work with it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I need some help with my code. It looks something like this.

I have code:

```
    my_list = 16
    my_dict = {1 : "b", 2 : "b", 3 : "x", 4 : "x", 5: "y", 6 : "z" , 7 : "z", 8 : "z", 9: "z"} my_list = 16 



new_list=[] for j, k in my_dict.iteritems():
            for j in range(my_list):
                   if k == k and j == 1:
                       new_list.append("hello")
                   elif k == k and j == 6:
                       new_list.append("helloagain")
                   else:
                       new_list.append("bye")
```

my new_list looks like

```
newList = ['bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye']
```

But I want to get

```
new_list = ['bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'helloagain', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye']
```

Comment: You're using the same variable `j` in both for loops. At least  change the inner loop to use `l` instead of `j` - or even better, give your variables actual names

Comment: Rather than saying "I want to do something like this" explain more about what you want to get in the end. i.e. what does new_list represent. Sharing your incomplete code helps us to understand your approach so that people can tailor their suggestions to you - but explanation of what you want to get is more important.

Comment: Also, `k` will always equal `k` and you need `j == 6` instead of `=`..

Comment: your code is **not properly indented**. Eg: `elif  block`

Comment: I switched there was a  = missing.

Comment: Why do you have my_list=16 If both key and value sum to 18? Is there any more information you are failing to provide?

Comment: No I just want to search from range(16) through keys in dictionary. Why would it matter how many values and keys are int he dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the purpose of the dict. If you only want one of the output you mentioned, you can simply skip the first for loop:

```
my_list = 16
new_list = []

for j in range(my_list):
    if j == 1:
        new_list.append("hello")
    elif j == 6
        new_list.append("helloagain")
    else:
        new_list.append("bye")
```

That way, you'll get:

```
new_list = [hello, bye, bye, bye, bye, helloagain, bye, bye, bye, bye, bye, bye, bye, bye, bye]
```

But again, that will not involve the dictionary. Did the problem you were trying to solve directly involve the dict? If so what is the desired output (what should be in new_list)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effor. Purpose of the dict is that keys are the same as range of my list. I need to iterate through my list to see if a input in my list lets say 1 is the same as my key in my dict and if values of the dict are the same then you append "hello" or "hello again" depends of the key.

Comment: So you only want to append to new_list until you get a value in the dict larger than 16?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer "I need to iterate through my list to see if a input in my list lets say 1 is the same as my key in my dict and if values of the dict are the same...". Same to what exactly?

Comment: Yes Im sorry my mistake I tried to rush it. I understand it it was just a mistake. Thanks for the correction. I understand how the for loop works I am just bothered how would I involve a dictionary and how would I only use keys which have the same value. If that is more clear.